Did the United States have consent from Texas to cede a piece of land that was part of Texas?
The Boundary Treaty of 1970, negotiated during the Nixon administration and ratified by the Senate, ceded to Mexico the Horcón Tract, a piece of land that was part of the state of Texas.
I can't find any evidence that the state of Texas consented (i.e. by an act of its legislature) to having a piece of its territory given away to a foreign country—but then again, I only have access to Google, and the online system to search Texas legislation only goes back to 1993, so it's quite possible that there is something that I'm simply not able to find.
From a constitutional standpoint, I would find it surprising if the federal government could shrink a US state without its consent... but my question here is not a legal question, but a historical one. Did Texas give consent, or not?

Interesting question. I'm not sure such permission would have been constitutionally required though. Still, would probably have been a good idea to get it just to be safe. Article 4 Section 3 seems the most relevant, probably Clause 2 since it wasn't an admission or internal shuffling of state territory. However, one could instead argue Congress has the sole authority to ratify treaties, which is what that was. Article 1 Section 10 Clause 1. If Texas wants to claim territory that the USA doesn't that's its business (but it can't declare war w/o Congress either).

@T.E.D.: We know from our old friend the migratory bird treaty that you can use treaties to override state law, but even that expansive power does not extend to overriding the US Constitution itself.

It's interesting to note that in this case, the territory in question was a de facto Mexican settlement already. It was south of the Rio Grande, and it took 60 years plus a geography professor before anyone even noticed that it was technically still U.S. land.  The transfer didn't elicit much opposition because Texas didn't really consider it theirs to begin with. The treaty simply made official what was already assumed to be true. Trying to cede populated land that was under the control of the state would almost certainly been received quite differently.

Does Texas have legislation or convention respecting riverine boundaries for their county and lower level constituencies? That might have a bearing even though international borders are a federal issue.

@T.E.D. the power to ratify treaties rests with the Senate, not with Congress.

@phoog - "Congress" = Senate + House of Representatives. Thus powers exclusive to the Senate, and powers exclusive to the House, and powers shared by both (but no other branch), are all powers of Congress. See Article 1 Section 1

@T.E.D. when the constitution grants a power to "Congress" it usually means "both houses with Presidential assent or with a veto override."  When there is a power that is particular to the Senate, it uses the word "Senate."  There's no point in confusing things by saying that Congress possesses those powers; among other things, it implies that members of the House of Representatives have some role to play, which they do not.  It is significant that the power to advise and consent on treaties (and appointments) is granted in Article 2 as a check on the executive, not in Article 1.

Nonetheless, it is a fact that the power is exclusive to Congress. Yes, specifically to the Senate body, but the point is Congress, not the states. I don't like to confuse issues with irrelevant levels of detail. It makes it read like there's something important that required that level of detail, when there wasn't. See Chekov's Gun on the inadvisability of bringing up unnecessary details when telling a story.

@T.E.D. precision isn't unnecessary detail.  Saying "Congress" in fact imprecisely introduces excessive (and worse, incorrect) detail, for it implies that consent is granted by an act of congress, which it is not.  Congress's collective role is legislative; the Senate has additional non-legislative roles in appointments, impeachment trials, and treaties.  Hamilton wrote in Federalist 65 of these being granted to the Senate "in a distinct capacity." And one reason for giving treaty ratification to the Senate was indeed because the states are equally represented there (Fed. 64).

No, they didn't seek such consent. If they did, that would have been a big deal, and the evidence would be on the Internet.
Although the intent of the question is about the historical fact and not legal interpretation, the question is fundamentally based on an incorrect legal premise. Both the Treaty Clause and the Supremacy Clause of the Constitution were precisely intended to ensure that states could be forced to comply with treaties, since this was a problem under the Articles of Confederation. As early as 1796 in Ware v. Hinton, the Supreme Court affirmed that federal treaty obligations take precedence over state laws. I can find no evidence that any state has ever had any traction trying to challenge this in court.
So from a strictly legal perspective, there is no reason to "find it surprising if the federal government could shrink a US state without its consent". Rather, it would have been surprising (and therefore likely to be widely reported) if Texas had been asked to consent to a treaty. Articles about the 1970 treaty like those cited in the Wikipedia page and others (e.g. Wilson 1980) would almost certainly mention this if it happened.
While the question focuses on one specific instance, there are many other cases in where the US has used its treaty power to exchange land and settle border disputes. In the case of the Mexican border, such changes are routinely handled by the International Boundary and Water Commission created in 1889. For the Canadian border, a similar body dates to the early 20th century. The power of these entities to make decisions without consulting local or state authorities has been politically controversial on multiple occasions, including the 1970 land exchange, but not actually challenged in any meaningful way.

The questioner may be thinking of the restrictions in the "New States" clause of the Constitution, which do indeed require the consent of a state for its partition - when that partition is in the form of admitting a new state to the union. There is nothing in the Constitution to suggest that the territorial integrity of a state is otherwise inviolable, and the very next clause empowers Congress to "dispose of and make all needful Rules and Regulations respecting the Territory or other Property belonging to the United States."
